# Where can I find the file object with the getImage API when the iOS location is not allowed by the user?

Tags: trigger.io

Where can I find the file object with the getImage API when the iOS location is not allowed by the user?

Will the error callback have the successful file object as shown here?

```
file.getImage( function (file) { /* the success scenario */ , function (file) { /* the error scenario but still has successful file object */ );
```

Or will the error callback have both the content and file objects?

```
file.getImage( function (file) { /* do success scenario  */ , function (content, file) { /* error scenario but has successful file object */ );
```

What would be the proper API pattern for this scenario?

Answer (score 1):

The reason the user might be prompted for location permission when you use `file.getImage` is because there is location data embedded the image's EXIF metadata which could be used to covertly infer their position.

This only occurs when you *read* data from the gallery: if you use the `saveLocation: "file"` parameter to [getImage](http://docs.trigger.io/en/v1.3/modules/file.html#getimage), the user won't be prompted for location permission.

In either case, the success callback for `file.getImage` should always be invoked with a file object (unless the user cancelled image capture entirely): it's only when you come to **use** the file that the location permission might be needed.